# How Python's compact dict lookup is performed, with int value inside the indicies?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm diggin in the `dict` structure in Python, and I'm trying to understand the implementation of **compact dict with faster iteration** explained here [[Python-Dev] More compact dictionaries with faster iteration by Raymond Hettinger](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-December/123028.html)

In this message, Raymond shows how the current dict implementation is and how it can be more memory efficient. He depict dict structure like this:

```
d = {'timmy': 'red', 'barry': 'green', 'guido': 'blue'}
```

> is currently stored as:

```
entries = [['--', '--', '--'],
           [-8522787127447073495, 'barry', 'green'],
           ['--', '--', '--'],
           ['--', '--', '--'],
           ['--', '--', '--'],
           [-9092791511155847987, 'timmy', 'red'],
           ['--', '--', '--'],
           [-6480567542315338377, 'guido', 'blue']]
```

> Instead, the data should be organized as follows:

```
indices =  [None, 1, None, None, None, 0, None, 2]
entries =  [[-9092791511155847987, 'timmy', 'red'],
            [-8522787127447073495, 'barry', 'green'],
            [-6480567542315338377, 'guido', 'blue']]
```

My question is **how does the new dict implementation performs lookup,** if the indices data is numerical 0, 1, 2, as the items were entered?
Is it just for clarity, and the actual value is different (eg, hash value of the key) ?

Some references I already looked [Dictionaries are ordered in Python 3.6+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/dictionaries-are-ordered-in-python-3-6)

Comment: There's a link to a recipe that was included on that webpage, you should consider taking a look at it: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578375/

Comment: I actually glanced over it, thanks for the suggestion I'll look into it deeper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing more research, I've found the answer I look for.

Python's regular dict allocates 24 byte indices in the array ([PyDictEntry](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Include/dictobject.h)). An empty dict in Python 2.7 consumes

```
d = dict()
import sys
sys.getsizeof(d)
272
```

(8 * 24 = 192 + overhead). And that's the dict entry object from the source code:

```
typedef struct {
    /* Cached hash code of me_key.  Note that hash codes are C longs.
     * We have to use Py_ssize_t instead because dict_popitem() abuses
     * me_hash to hold a search finger.
     */
    Py_ssize_t me_hash;  --> 8 bytes
    PyObject *me_key;  --> 8 bytes
    PyObject *me_value;  --> 8 bytes
} PyDictEntry;
```

With the new **compact dict**, the table is split to two: **indexes and entries**.
The indexes array is of `int` type (for empty to small dicts) which is 8 bytes. These are references to the actual index of the entry, if there is any. If it's empty it returns `None` (or dummy in case there were deletions). Then the entries list contains only allocated objects.

Using my example from the question, the dict with 3 entries in Python 3.6 would consume: indices (8 bytes) + entries (3 * 24 = 72) = 80 bytes + overhead.

That's pretty neat saving for the same data with little to no impact on performance.

When lookup is performed it looks in the *indexes* table. Then it uses the returned value to *read / append* an entry to the *entries* list.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but there's a talk in which Raymond Hettinger explains the details and inception of the compact dict and also briefly mentions the key sharing feature of instance dicts.
    https://youtu.be/p33CVV29OG8

Here you can read more about the key sharing dicts.
    https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0412/